# Why the result differs when I press enter at the end of a sentence?

Tags: c++, cin, enter

Here is my first program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    string s;
    double d;
    while(cin >> a >> s >> d)
        cout << a << s << d;
    return 0;
}
```

When I input some simple data and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> , the result is shown immediately:

[image]

However, the code in another program behaves differently:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Sales_data {
    string bookNo;
    unsigned units_sold = 0;
    double price = 0.0;
    void Print();
};

void Sales_data::Print(){//print every record of the Sales_data
    cout << "The bookNo of the book is " << bookNo << endl;
    cout << "The units_sold of the book is " << units_sold << endl;
    cout << "The price of the book is " << price << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Sales_data book;
    while(cin >> book.bookNo >> book.units_sold >> book.price);
        book.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, input some data, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it waits for me to input more data rather than show the result.

[image]

Could you explain this to me?

Comment: Not sure about MSVC (Visual Studio), but other compilers [are capable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a11a443f471e1f5) of telling you that there's something up. It's often worth trying more than one to see warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after the `while` loop. As it is, it forces the loop to have no body, which means it just cycles over the `cin` forever. Even better, use braces to delimit the body:

```
while(cin >> book.bookNo >> book.units_sold >> book.price) {
    book.Print();
}
```